# Different new order emails based on customer group

Tags: magento-1.8, email-templates, customer-group

I want to customise the new order email based upon the customer group. Ideally it would be great to have separate email templates for each group.

I have found the following plugin http://goo.gl/1JOsHR however wanted to know if this is the best way to go about this before I brought it or if there is a better extension  or method out there

Comment: What type of customization do you want to do, is this just simple text changes or more complex design changes?

Comment: For 2 of the groups simple text changes but for another 2 I want a complete design change

Answer (score 4):

To send different order conformation email depending on specific criteria you would either have to :

1. Rewrite `sendNewOrderEmail()` in Mage_Sales_Model_Order and add logic to check the template
2. Disable magento "order confirmation email" in system config, then create a custom module to send your email by coping logic from sendNewOrderEmail() using event/observer
3. For simple text changes, you could use template logic `{{if order.customer_group_id}}` or `{{depend order.customer_group_id}}` but they seem to only evaluate true/false condition, therefore for more advance logic you could include a block

> {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='sales/custom_logic.phtml' order=$order}}

In custom_logic.phtml

```
<?php
  $order = $this->getOrder()

  if($order->getCustomerGroupId() == 1){
     ///do
   ....
```

See [Magento Email Template If Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797394/magento-email-template-if-statements)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Renon's answer. I found that using

`$order->getCustomerGroupId()`

could sometimes cause the logic to break for some templates. I later chose to get the groupid with the below code. Hope it helps someone.

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

echo $customer->getGroupId();
```